# PHP cURL error regarding SSL

Tags: php, curl, ssl

The error I'm getting when I try to connect to a server over HTTPS:

`Curl error: error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: cacert.pem CApath: /etc/ssl/certs`

I have this line in the top of my php.ini file: `curl.cainfo=/etc/php5/apache2/cacert.pem`, the cacert.pem file exists and I've set the the permission to 777, just to make sure that permissions is not the problem. The same for `/etc/ssl/certs`.

My PHP code is

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://google.com");
$res = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Why did you add that extra line to your php.ini?

Comment: @MartinKonecny I read somewhere that curl needs that file, you can either manually say where it's located (when you need to make a connection over HTTPS/SLL), or you can add that line in the ini. If you don't specify it cURL will throw another error saying it doesn't know where the CAfile is...

Comment: By default curl should be able to find public key information of the all registered certificate authorities provided by your OS. Have you tried without that line?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have been in my PHP setup being outdated. I completely removed php_curl, then installed it again, that solved the problem for me. I realized that the problem could be in the package being outdated because running curl in the terminal worked just fine.